# Forgot Password Logic in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, forgot-password

can someone please explain me the logic of forgot password procedure i.e how can I implement a forgot password logic while using codeigniter framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For forgot password, first take user id i.e. `User email` for authorizing him i.e. search in your database where any user exist of such email...

Now after authorizing, generate random password and at the same time update that database entry with random password and send that random password to the user via Email....

After user login with that user ask user to update his/her password